# How to install Feynmf or Feynmp on Mac OS X?

Tags: feynmf

I really need your help, several times I have tried to install Feynmf or Feynmp on my mac but I failed, my main problem is working with the terminal which I think one needs to install these two packages. I have used the guides from CTAN.
Is there anyway to tell me step by step how to use the terminal and install Feynmf or Feynmp? many thanks.

Comment: Those appear to be part of TeX Live. Just install MacTeX and you should be ready to go.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you by chance install BasicTeX? Or what other TeX distribution?

Comment: Yes I have MacTex, but I think as i mentioned my problem is how to install Feynmf.

Comment: I've also had MacTeX (2013) installed and `feynmf` is here: `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/metapost/feynmf`. Can you provide a minimal document making use of `feynmf` which doesn't work with your installation of MacTeX? Or is it that you need, for some reason, to install it twice?

Comment: Thnaks fpst, actually I can not install it, this is the main problem...I followed all the steps from CTAN but it did not wok so I have to install it again...but I do not know how. I have installed my MacTex in 2010, but I update it frequently.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you've tried to install something (`feynmp`) that was already installed in MacTeX 2010, and this installation didn't work, so yo want to install it again? But MacTeX 2010 is long outdated anyway. It is better to download MacTeX 2013 and install it. In particular, `feynmp` will be reinstalled from scratch and it will probably work. Unless you had installed `feynmp` in one of your local directories (`/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` or `~/Library/texmf`). In that cas remove `feynmp`first from these directories before reinstalling MacTeX.

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. I just installed MacTeX 2013, so I tried very simple Feynman graph but I got the following error: ''Enviroment fmfgraph undefined''. the graph was:       \usepackage{feyn}
\begin{document}                                     \begin{fmfgraph}(40,30)                               \fmfpen{thick}
              \fmfleft{i1,i2} \fmfright{o1,o2}
              \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1} \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
              \fmf{photon,label=$q$}{v1,v2} \fmfdot{v1,v2}
            \end{fmfgraph}\end{document}